# How to compare MethodHandle instances?

Tags: java, methodhandle

How do I compare two `MethodHandle` instances? I am expecting the function to return true if the handles point to the same method. It doesn't look like the class overrides `equals()` or `hashcode()`. Is it safe to use the equality operator (`==`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `MethodHandle`s may not only encapsulate a target method but also a *behavior*. E.g. you may have two method handles pointing to the same method but one encapsulating a non-virtual (`super. …`) call and one representing an ordinary virtual invocation. These handles can’t be equal.

Besides that, there is no defined equality for `MethodHandle`s anyway. They are there to allow *invocation* but not *introspection*:

[JVMSpec §5.4.3.5. Method Type and Method Handle Resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.5-400):

> An implementation of the Java Virtual Machine is not required to intern method types or method handles. That is, two distinct symbolic references to method types or method handles which are structurally identical might not resolve to the same instance of `java.lang.invoke.MethodType` or `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` respectively.

---

However, starting with Java 8 there is a feature that allows to introspect a *direct* `MethodHandle`, [`Lookup.revealDirect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#revealDirect-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-). For handles for which this operation succeeds, you can use the information in the returned [`MethodHandleInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleInfo.html) to find out whether two handles point to the same method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give an example of a non-direct `MethodHandle` and how it is constructed?

Comment: Most of the handles returned by the factory methods in [`MethodHandles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html) are non-direct method handles. Simply said, handles which do not directly target a method, constructor or field but rather modify the behavior of another handle are non-direct handles. But also [the constant wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#constant-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) which does not modify another handle (but hasn’t a specific target method) is non-direct.